# DB4O - Update depth issue

Tags: db4o

Using DB4O. I have an object1 which is composed with object2, like so:

```
public class Object1Class {

   private Object2Class;

}
```

If I delete object1, the associated object2 will be deleted, no problems there.

However, if I delete object2, object1 still contains object2. Ideally, when I delete object2, object1 should show a null reference to object2.

So, my hunch is that DB4o is cascading on update DOWN the object tree, but it is not cascading UP the object tree.

Am I right?

If it's not clear, my goal is to update a parent object when a child object is updated, altered or deleted.

***- Perhaps I need to call`.store()`on the parent object AFTER I update the child object?***

***- Will`transparent persistence`solve this problem?***

Here is my configuration:

```
EmbeddedConfiguration config = Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration();
config.file().generateUUIDs(ConfigScope.GLOBALLY);
config.common().objectClass(MyModel.class).cascadeOnDelete(true);
config.common().objectClass(MyModel.class).cascadeOnUpdate(true);
config.common().objectClass(MyModel.class).cascadeOnActivate(true);
config.common().updateDepth(5);
config.common().activationDepth(5);
```

Also, please note that all my persisted classes inherit the MyModel class.

Here is some info on update depth:

[DB4o Update Depth info](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/configuration/common/update_depth.htm)

Answer (score 1):

db4o tries to blend as much as possible to the the "OOP" philosophy, meaning, it'll try to follow normal OOP concepts.

In this case, it will not try to track references from childs to parents (.net/java runtime also does not track such references).

What you can do in this case is to add a field in the child pointing back to its parent and, whenever the client gets updated, update its parent accordingly (you can use [db4o callbacks](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/net35/reference/Content/advanced_topics/callbacks.htm) for that)

Comment: thank you, yet another example of why Java and other OOP languages should automatically track these relationships.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are working in memory on deleting and in database when you query
 Have done a *commit()* after delete?

I encourage to use TA/TP which manage very well those problems.

Best regards
Claude